# springboot with thymeleaf two way binding

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

I'm trying to use thymeleaf with springboot. but some problems happened and I don't why.

Here's my code：

```
@GetMapping
public String main(Model model) {

    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("field1", "value1");
    map.put("field1", "value1");

    model.addAttribute("myMap", map);
    return "index";
}
```

and here's the html:

```
<div class="nav" th:each="myEntry:${myMap}">
     <label th:text="${myEntry.getKey()}"></label>
     <input th:value="${myEntry.getValue()}">
     <button class="btn" th:onclick="'javascript:trigger()'">Trigger</button>

</div>
```

As you can see in the java and html。I set a key-value pair for the model, and use it's key as a label, value as a input. When I change the value of the input field. The values(that is myMap) in the model don't change.

Anyone knows why or how?

Answer (score 0):

The way that thymeleaf works here is that it takes the template, injects the model and serves it to the client, this is called server side rendering.

When you change the value in the input field you are making changes client side and the HTML is not related to the server side at all, as all backend does is serves your page.

If you want a back and forth communication between browser and server typically people use web sockets. Here's an example [from spring.io on using websockets](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/)

Comment: It's not about I changed the input field value that so server side should also change that value. It's about when I change the input field value, so that I can get that value on the client side, so that I can send a post to save the changes

Comment: If you are changing the value in the input field the `value` is changing. i.e., if you have an input field and you change value then client side value changes. If you want to then take the changed value and send it to back end you need to use form submission (https://spring.io/guides/gs/handling-form-submission/)